# Problema al realizar solicitud POST con fecha en Vue y Django

Tags: javascript, django, vue.js

Espero puedan brindarme su orientación en un problema que estoy enfrentando en un proyecto Django y Vue. Estoy intentando pasar una fecha a otro componente a través de una URL y realizar una solicitud POST con esta fecha. Aparentemente, el componente receptor recibe la fecha de manera correcta, ya que el registro de la fecha se imprime de manera precisa en los registros. Sin embargo, la solicitud POST está generando un error.

Hasta ahora, he implementado la misma lógica con otros componentes, pasando documentos o nombres, y ha funcionado correctamente.

Este es el error

```
cod: undefined
datos: undefined
mensaje: "Se ha presentado un error. Intente recargando la página, si persiste reporte a soporte técnico (código undefined)."
res: undefined
```

La solicitud

```
export const solicitud = async (url, datos) => {
  const respuesta = {
    mensaje: 'Se ha presentado un error. Intente recargando la página, si persiste reporte a soporte técnico',
  };

  try {
    const respuestaBE = await axios.post(url, datos);
    
    respuesta.res = respuestaBE.data.res;
    respuesta.cod = respuestaBE.data.cod;
    respuesta.datos = respuestaBE.data.datos;
    
    respuesta.mensaje = respuesta.res ? null : `${respuesta.mensaje} (código ${respuesta.cod}).`;
      
    return respuesta;
  }
  catch (error) {
    const respuestaError = error.toJSON();
    console.log(respuestaError);
    respuesta.mensaje = `${respuesta.mensaje} (código 500).`;
  };
}
```

Aquí está cómo estoy enviando la fecha a través de una URL en mi código HTML:

```
                <tr v-for="rueda in informe" :key="rueda.rueda">
                  <td>{{ rueda.rueda }}</td>
                  <td>{{ rueda.fecha }}</td>
                  <td>{{ rueda.num_operaciones }}</td>
                  <td>{{ formatoMoneda(rueda.negociado) }}</td>
                  <td>{{ formatoMoneda(rueda.comision) }}</td>
                  <td><a :href="`/informes/operaciones/rueda/${rueda.fecha}/`">Ver</a>
                  </td>
                </tr>
```

Este es el componente que recibe la fecha y donde se realiza la solicitud POST:

```
export default {
    name: 'Rueda',
    data() {
        return {
            informe: [],

            fecha: fecha,

        };
    },
    methods: {
        async obtenerInforme() {
            if (this.fecha) {
                console.log("Fecha seleccionada:", this.fecha) // correcto
                const respuesta = await solicitud('/informes/operaciones/rueda/obtener/', { fecha: this.fecha });
                console.log("Respuesta:", respuesta); // error
                this.informe = respuesta.datos;
            } else {
                console.error("Fecha no seleccionada");
            }
        }
    },
```

Luego, esta es la consulta en Django:

```
@manejar_respuesta(Operaciones)
def consulta_rueda(datos):
    fecha = datos.get("fecha")
    print(fecha)

    resultado = (
        Operaciones.objects.filter(fecha=fecha)
        .values("comitente_doc", "comitente", "rueda")
        .annotate(
            ...
    )
    print(resultado)
    respuesta = list(resultado)

    return enviar_respuesta(respuesta)
```

Además, aquí están las rutas en urls.py:

```
path('operaciones/rueda/<str:fecha>/', views.rueda_diaria, name='rueda_diaria'),
path('operaciones/rueda/obtener/', rueda_diaria.consulta_rueda),
```

La vista en Django:

```
@login_required
def rueda_diaria(request, fecha):
    return render(request, 'informes/operaciones/rueda-diaria.html', {
        'pagina_titulo': APP_NAME + ': Rueda',
        'fecha': fecha
    })
```

Agradezco de antemano cualquier orientación o sugerencia para identificar y solucionar este problema.

Comment: @padaleiana Tienes razon, lo olvide por completo, ya agregue el error que me aparece y como hago la solicitud.